# Kubernetes Jenkins plugin - waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I am using the Kubernetes plugin for Jenkins, and it seems to have an issue pulling from my private Docker registry.

This is an "untrusted" (no SSL) Harbor private registry.

When I got another Jenkins pipeline to pull from the registry, I had to set `--insecure-registry http://10.3.31.105 --insecure-registry 10.3.31.105` in the `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker-options.conf` file.
I wonder if there is anything special that I need to do in order to enable Kubernetes to use an untrusted registry in a similar fashion?

This is my pod in use and the error that I am receiving:

```
[svc.jenkins@node1 ~]$ kubectl get pods
NAME                               READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
message-service-7d9494544d-fvnkl   0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          1m
[svc.jenkins@node1 ~]$ kubectl logs message-service-7d9494544d-fvnkl
Error from server (BadRequest): container "message-service" in pod "message-service-7d9494544d-fvnkl" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image
```

The Jenkins job, however, exits successfully:

```
Finished Kubernetes deployment
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

Your workflow environment lacks [Kubernetes secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/).

Kubernetes use those secrets
  as credentials to pull an image of the registry when executed by Jenkins.
It is always a bad habit to leave the registry unprotected, so you should stop providing command line parameters to force an insecure registry.
To use credentials in a pipeline, you do not need to do anything special,
you access them just as you would for credentials stored in Jenkins.

I found this [kubernetes-credentials-provider-plugin](https://jenkinsci.github.io/kubernetes-credentials-provider-plugin/) useful, and another working 
 [kubernetes-cd-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-cd-plugin) here.

Comment: Does this actually answer the question of "why is this error happening"? This is a development and proof of concept environment and not accessible to anyone but devs and we do not care even the slightest about security right now.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the a bit like you were doing:
Edit the file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and add:

```
{
    "insecure-registries" : [ "10.3.31.105:5000" ]
}
```

It's recommended to put daemon options in the the `daemon.json` and not just adding them to your docker daemon service. You'll need to do this on every node in your Kubernetes cluster. This will allow kubernetes to pull images from untrusted registries.